# Call method from other ViewController | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, viewcontroller

I searched to solving this problem a lot of questions but no one helped me.
Have 2 viewControllers and I need to send array from one to another.

Calling method in the first viewController:

```
   SubmitViewController.acceptContent(content)
```

Accepting in other:

```
var contentAccepted = [String]()

class func acceptContent(content: [String]){

    contentAccepted = content

}
```

The problem is in taking the mistake on contentAccepted line: Instance member cannot be used on type `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that `contentAccepted` is an instance variable (as it should be) and `acceptContent()` is a class method. So, your method can't get to your variable. You will need to create an instance of `SubmitViewController` before you are able to access its variables.

```
let submitViewController = SubmitViewController()
submitViewController.contentAccepted = content
```

By first creating a SubmitViewController instance, you can now access that instance variable.

If you are passing information from one View Controller to another in the midst of a segue, you might consider using [`prepareForSegue`](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/).

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "Submit" {
            if let view = segue.destinationViewController as? SubmitViewController {
                view.contentAccepted = content // If content is an instance variable
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, so when i send array from first view to another, and my current view is second, the accepted array is empty. why?

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't give your second View Controller an identifier? One way to test this is to remove the `if segue.identifier .... ` bit. I use that in View Controllers I know will have several segues. If you know for a fact that `segue` is going to be the `SubmitViewController` then test it without the `if` statement.

Comment: i use a button for performSegueWithIdentifier("Submit", sender: self) for changing the views. so how can i still use the button and prepareForSegue?

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier` will automatically trigger `prepareForSegue`. So, the issue might be that your segue isn't named (in the storyboard) or that you are using the wrong identifier in `prepareForSegue`. I updated my answer to reflect your "Submit" identifier. I would lay out some breakpoints to ensure everything is getting called. If not, determine at what point code is not running and why.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to self within your type-method.
Here is what apple says on that matter:

> Within the body of a type method, the implicit self property refers to
>   the type itself, rather than an instance of that type. For structures
>   and enumerations, this means that you can use self to disambiguate
>   between type properties and type method parameters, just as you do for
>   instance properties and instance method parameters.
>
> More generally, any unqualified method and property names that you use
>   within the body of a type method will refer to other type-level
>   methods and properties. A type method can call another type method
>   with the other method’s name, without needing to prefix it with the
>   type name. Similarly, type methods on structures and enumerations can
>   access type properties by using the type property’s name without a
>   type name prefix.

[More info on type-methods (class-methods) can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

Try to do it that way:

```
var contentAccepted = [String]()

class func acceptContent(content: [String]){

    ViewController().contentAccepted = content

}
```

Make sure that you really need type-method.